# Identify which users are accessing M365 Apps from mobile devices

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I need to get a report of how many users access any M365 apps like SharePoint, Planner, Teams etc. from mobile device.

Is there any options available in M365 Admin Center or PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this information in usage report.

[image: usage data]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Microsoft 365 admin center >> Reports >> Usage page, select product in the left navigation >> Device usage. Click the "Export" button to export the usage report to a .csv file.
**[image: strong text]**